# Django_compressor error with Sass. Cannot @import files

Tags: django, sass, django-compressor

I am trying to use Sass to compile a style.scss file with django_compressor.

I have found that Sass works on the command line if I am in the css directory, but if I am in any other directory it produces the same error as below.

```
Caught FilterError while rendering: Syntax error: File to import not found or unreadable: helpers.scss
Load path: .
on line 28 of d:\siphon\siphon\static\css\style.scss
```

How can I fix this error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

take a look at [Compass](http://compass-style.org/). It compiles your sass to a css and only then you get compressor to do it's job.

Comment: Many times people ask a detail question, where they only want a solution to the bigger problem.
But yes, it's not an answer to the question.